# Mozilla Addon Development check environment

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox add on, I pretend my add on to be able to run in both desktop and mobile devices. I think more or less everything is compatible with both environments, however there are pieces of code that I would like to run depending on whether the current device is mobile or desktop, so the question is if there is something like `system.isMobile()` that can be used in the following way:

```
var system = require("sdk/system");
if(system.isMobile())
    console.log("firefox for android");
else
    console.log("normal firefox");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can find at the [system api documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/system), there is a variable telling the operating system.

**code**:

```
var system = require("sdk/system");
console.log("system platform = " + system.platform);
```

**output**:

```
system platform = linux
```

disclaimer: I didn't tested on mobile environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [System High-Level API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/system). [`system.platform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/system#platform) will contain the information on the type of OS the user is running.

You can use it like so:

```
var system = require("sdk/system");
var platform = system.platform // Will contain platform, i.e. Windows, Linux, etc.

// You can log this data to the console
console.log("System Platform = " + platform);
```

When you call `system.platform`, it will usually return one of the values listed on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/OS_TARGET), converted to lowercase